# Avoid merging from Cross-Tab report

Tags: java, crosstab, dynamic-reports

I am using **Dynamic Report** builder to create a cross-tab report in Java. I am able to create the report but the issue is it merges cells with the same value. Is there any option in Dynamic Reports to avoid this merging?

I have tried

```
crossTab.setRepeatColumnHeaders(true);
crossTab.setRepeatRowHeaders(true);
```

But this is not working. Now the report coming like this:

[image]

I want to repeat the `1-Each-Ketchup, 1-Each-Yellow Mustard` value in the next row also.

Comment: What's your data source?

Comment: post what you have tried.